# Unable create/access storage pool in a KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7, virsh

I have trouble using storage pools in my KVM setup.

I get the following error message whenever I try to use a pool-* command in my virsh shell.

```
virsh # pool-list
error: Failed to get the number of active pools
error: this function is not supported by the connection driver: virConnectNumOfStoragePools
```

Rest of my virsh commands seem to work fine.
My KVM host is running on Centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error. The solution I came to is that I needed to do a `yum update` first. Afterwords, I restarted libvirtd with `systemctl restart libvirtd`.

This cleared up my issue. so now I can get a pool-list just fine.

I traced it back to [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1164773) which led me to just updating all of the packages.